# Labels are not displayed on my Scatter Plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I wrote a code to draw a scatter plot based on data from my Data Frame.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as snd  

import_data = np.loadtxt('persona 5.csv', delimiter = ';' , dtype = object)

plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
plt.scatter(display_persona['Base level'], display_persona['Strength'])
plt.scatter(display_persona['Base level'], display_persona['Magic'])
plt.scatter(display_persona['Base level'], display_persona['Endurance'])
plt.scatter(display_persona['Base level'], display_persona['Agility'])
plt.scatter(display_persona['Base level'], display_persona['Luck'])
plt.xlabel= ("Base Level of Personas")

plt.show()
```

[Output I have gotten is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vixOA.png)

I have noticed that x labels and y labels are not displayed. Furthermore, I also would like to which color is what value and unfortunately I'm stuck to make this scatter easier to understand.

How can I improve this scatter of mine ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the equal sign. It should be:

```
plt.xlabel("Base Level of Personas")
```

To show a legend corresponding to the colors:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
plt.scatter(display_persona['Base level'], display_persona['Strength'], label = 'Strength')
plt.scatter(display_persona['Base level'], display_persona['Magic'], label = 'Magic')
plt.scatter(display_persona['Base level'], display_persona['Endurance'], label = 'Endurance')
plt.scatter(display_persona['Base level'], display_persona['Agility'], label = 'Agility')
plt.scatter(display_persona['Base level'], display_persona['Luck'], label = 'Luck')
plt.xlabel("Base Level of Personas")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I did not even noticed that equal sign until you point it out. Damn me. Thanks for the assist !